# Truncating and removing characters from char array C++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, char

I basically have a `txt` file that looks like this...

```
High Score: 50
Player Name: Sam
Number Of Kills: 5
Map
Time
```

I want to store everything before the `:` or whitespace after `Map` and `Time` into one array and everything after in another. For both `Map` and `Time`, there is nothing after and so I want to store the whitespace as `null`.

So far, I have managed to read and store all this information into a `temp` array. However, it is separating that I am having trouble with. This is my code:

```
istream operator >> (istream &is, Player &player)
{
  char **temp;
  char **tempNew;
  char lineInfo[200]
  temp = new char*[5];
  tempNew = new char*[5];
  for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
  {
    temp[i] = new char[200];
    is.getline(lineInfo, sizeof(lineInfo));
    int length = strlen(lineInfo);
    for (int z=0; z < length; z++)
    {
      if(lineInfo[z] == '= ' ){  //HOW DO I CHECK IF THERE IS NOTHING AFTER THE LAST CHAR
        lineInfo [length - (z+1)] = lineInfo [length];
        cout << lineInfo << endl;
        strncpy(temp[i], lineInfo, sizeof(lineInfo));
      }
      else{
        tempNew[i] = new char[200];
        strncpy(tempNew[i], lineInfo, sizeof(lineInfo));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You `new` but you never `delete []`, which will leak memory. Instead, use `std::string` and `std::vector` so you don't need to allocate memory directly (and then you don't need to use C string functions, either).

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is to find ':'

```
#include <cstring>
```

and just
    `auto occurance = strstr(string, substring);`

Documentation [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/).

if occurance is not a null ptr, then see if occurance is at the end of the line from get line. If not, your value is everything after that :

Comment: Thanks. What about whitespaces? For example, after `map` there is no colon but I want to store everything after `map` as `null`. Would really appreciate it if you could help modify my code

Comment: You can use the bool isspace(char c) function. To be honest this is very c string related code and would benefit from switching to c++ #include <string> if you can

Comment: Then it would probably be a better idea to just do it all in c and use functional programming. Why use c++?

Answer (score 0):

Much easier with `std::string`.

```
// Read high score
int high_score;
my_text_file.ignore(10000, ':');
cin >> high_score;

// Read player name
std::string player_name;
my_text_file.ignore(10000, ':');
std::getline(my_text_file, player_name);  

// Remove spaces at beginning of string
std::string::size_type end_position;
end_position = player_name.find_first_not_of(" \t");
if (end_position != std::string::npos)
{
  player_name.erase(0, end_position - 1);
}

// Read kills
unsigned int number_of_kills = 0;
my_text_file.ignore(':');
cin >> number_of_kills;

// Read "Map" line
my_text_file.ignore(10000, '\n');
std::string map_line_text;
std::getline(my_text_file, map_line_text);

// Read "Text" line
std::string text_line;
std::getline(my_text_file, text_line);
```

If you insist on using C-style strings (arrays of `char`), you will have to use more complex and less safe functionality.  Look up the following functions:

```
fscanf, strchr, strcpy, sscanf
```

Comment: thanks for this alternative method. Since my code is being used for high scores in a game, I am willing to learn new alternatives. As for my `c style` approach, how would I get it to do what you did with `string`?

Comment: Compile as C++, include the appropriate headers.  Read good reference book on C++?